# Right aligning image for Outlook email

Tags: html, css

I right align my image using float.

```
<div align="left">
   Insight
   <img height="20" style="float:right;" src="https://mydomain/myimage.jpeg">
</div>
```

I send this html as an email. However,  in microsoft outlook the image does not right align because I think ms outtlook does not support float.

Is there any other way to right align it?

Comment: tables is your answer :)

Comment: Is my answer what you were looking for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tables, nested tables and more tables is the key for Outlook.

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="top">
            <img height="20" src="https://mydomain/myimage.jpeg">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: In addition, we use td's with a transparent gif and fixed width and height for padding, and `<font style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px; color: #000000">` for all text styling.