# Hotmail (live.mail) css float not supported?

Tags: css, css-float, html-email, hotmail, floating

Trying a whole bunch of different ways to get my elements to float (which all work in gmail etc) in hotmail.

< div class="plzfloat" id="floats" style="float:left"> 
 #floats{float:left;} .plzfloat { float:left;}

I even added css rules for a class and id that would add the float rule but when I view it in hotmail all my floats have been stripped out of my email.

Been searching google but haven't had any luck finding sources saying float isn't supported by hotmail - anyone have any experience with this?

Cheers,
Ian

Comment: If you are doing emails, you are in a verry bad dirrection using inlined .css.

For cross-browser, plateform, software email messaging, use plain html 4, no positioning, no css

Otherwise, You're rife with everyday pox will FOR SURE become a headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't code emails the same way as you do for web.

Here is a resource for starting out in HTML email: http://www.reachcustomersonline.com/how-to-code-html-email-newsletters-all-new-version/

It will get you started on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing emails, you should use tables, tables, tables and tables for everything.
This especially applies to clients developed by Microsoft.

[Right aligning image for Outlook email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438148/right-aligning-image-for-outlook-email/14439353#14439353)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get my divs to "float" by first defining a div container width forcing anything within the container to break once the width is filled. Within the container I then set-up child divs and set their style's to display: inline;.

This way they align next to each other but then automatically break at a particular width. I hope that helps!

I tested in outlook and it actually rendered.

~Dianne

Answer (score 0):

Yes Because of the simple fact that live is no longer good and not web supported.